# Autofac singleton dispose

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, owin, autofac

I just want to make sure about singletons disposal in *Autofac*. If I register a component as singleton in *Autofac* it's `Dispose` method is fired when the application is shut down?

At the moment I hold the component in the `Startup` and call it's dispose in `OnShutDown` which I register in `OnAppDisposing`. Thought it would be more elegant to set this thing with *Autofac*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html) says :

> If you have singleton components (registered as SingleInstance()) they will live for the life of the container. Since container lifetimes are usually the application lifetime, it means the component won’t be disposed until the end of the application.
>
> > http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html

If you want *Autofac* calls the `Dispose` method on a `SingleInstance` registration you will have to call the `Dispose` method of the container when the application shutdown.

This github issue discuss about it : [Should UseAutofacMiddleware dispose container on OWIN shutdown](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/565).

In beta version of *Autofac Owin Integration* you have a `DisposeContainerOnShutdown` extension method.

Starting with 4.0 version of `Autofac.Owin`, you can do this :

```
app.DisposeContainerOnShutdown(container);
```

With older version, you can copy/paste the `DisposeContainerOnShutdown` method from the [AutofacAppBuilderExtensions.cs](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Owin/blob/be1f12c195e939347bf5b5e91279030d0ea39054/src/Autofac.Integration.Owin/AutofacAppBuilderExtensions.cs) source code